# Checking individual records against grouped standard deviations

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

data:

```
                               Country        ITEM_TYPE   Ship Date  TOTAL_COST
0                                 Chad  Office Supplies   2/12/2011  2353920.64
1                               Latvia        Beverages   1/23/2016    34174.25
2                             Pakistan       Vegetables    2/1/2011   592408.95
3     Democratic Republic of the Congo        Household   10/6/2012  3861014.82
4                       Czech Republic        Beverages   12/5/2015   110978.89
5                         South Africa        Beverages   8/21/2012   314085.20
6                                 Laos       Vegetables   3/20/2011   438737.25
7                                China        Baby Food   5/12/2017   530868.60
8                              Eritrea             Meat   1/10/2015   886561.39
9                                Haiti  Office Supplies   7/20/2015  3253177.12
10                              Zambia           Cereal   8/24/2016    84787.64
```

I'd like to return all records where `TOTAL_COST` is greater than 2 standard deviations for the specific `COUNTRY` & `ITEM_TYPE` combination of that record.

I get the standard deviation for each combination using the following:

```
stdevs = data.groupby(['Country', 'ITEM_TYPE'])['TOTAL_COST'].std()
```

My first attempt was the following:

```
results = data[data['Total Cost'] > 2*stdevs[data[['Country']][data['Item Type']]]]
```

URL to dummy data used (10,000 records): http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-18-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-sales/

Comment: Do you mean greater than 2 standard deviations away from the mean?

Comment: Correct. I’m looking to return records 2 standard deviations away from the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can z-score normalize your data using `transform` after a groupby.

#### Sample Data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': list('AB')*20, 
                   'ITEM_TYPE': list('1122')*10,
                   'TOTAL_COST': np.random.randint(1, 500, 40)})
```

#### Code

```
gp = df.groupby(['Country', 'ITEM_TYPE'])
df['zscore'] = (df['TOTAL_COST'] - gp.TOTAL_COST.transform('mean'))/gp.TOTAL_COST.transform('std')

# Then filter
df[df.zscore.abs().gt(2)]
#  Country ITEM_TYPE  TOTAL_COST    zscore
#1       B         1         383  2.127847
```

Comment: If you print `df` it looks like the z-scores are being aggregated incorrectly. I re-created the z-scores in excel. The scores, from top to bottom, correspond to the A1, A2, B1, and B2 z-scores, in that order. To see what I mean, filter the data in excel by A1 items, and you'll see that the first 10 z-scores in the data correspond to the first 10 A1 items. Let me know if that's still unclear.

Comment: @ohBoy yes, seems to have been the case. See the update

Comment: Here's an example of the behavior I'm looking for: For the second record, which is a B1 record, I want the z-score for the `TOTAL_COST` of the record using the B1 mean and B1 stdev, which should be `143.2` and `112.6960514`, respectively. The z-score should be `2.1278474`.)